# Font size problem for a Matlab figure in a template

Tags: matlab, fonts, font-size, beamer

I know this is a topic that is closed but I am struggling to put a MATLAB figure in a beamer template with the adequate font size.

I started to use the `Export setup` of MATLAB to adjust the dimensions of my figure and also the font size which is `12 pts` :

[image]

This size is chosen because the font size of a frame title appears to be this value.
Then, I save it as an eps file and I check the dimensions with Inkscape : everything seems to be correct.

But when loading it in my beamer template, the font size seems to not be adequate anymore (see the difference between the font size of the title and the font size of the figure):

[image]

My coding is very basic since I am just loading my eps file in LaTex document after conversion to PDF `\usepackage{epstopdf}`  :

```
\includegraphics[width=1 \linewidth]{pic/test.eps}
```

Is there a simple way to make the font size of the figure similar to the font size of the title ?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: How about using a bigger font size in the export?

Comment: yes : but I don't understand why the 12 pt size of the export is not the 12 pt size of the beamer display ? This is strange...

Comment: It's probably 12pt at its native resolution, it will not retain that font-size dynamically when the image is scaled within the beamer display. Make the dimensions of the exported image smaller such that the relative font size is larger.

Comment: By default, the export size does not match the size on screen. You have to manually specify the size of the exported figure. Make the size such that you don’t need to scale it when importing in latex (no “width” argument).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your message : But what do you mean by the export size doesn't match the size on screen ? Because when exporting on MATLAB, I have already specified the dimensions of the figure (12 by 8 inches).

Comment: If you want to preserve the font size, don’t use the `width` argument when importing the figure into your latex document. You want to make sure the figure is not scaled, but inserted at its natural size. And you need to specify the right size when exporting the figure.

Comment: Figure windows have a “Position” property that specifies their location and size on screen, and a “PaperPosition” property that specifies the size and position on the “page” when exporting. If you export as PDF or Postscript, then there is also the “PaperSize” property that is relevant. Both are dependent on “PaperUnits”, which determines what the length units are. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#d124e449460